# Web application send sms from my mobile phone?

Tags: php, web, sms

I am from Romania and I am developing PHP Application for 1 year. I want to build now a web application that sends sms from web using my phone number. When the sms is send from the web, my sim card will be activated and will send that sms from my phone. Can you tell me please where to start with this? Thank you!

Comment: You need API integration with your carrier. I don't see any other option.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into? As it stands your question if far too broad. 
Please read [How to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: and what exactly means api integration with my carrier? where can I take the api? Do I have to ask them for the api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using android you could use the ADB Driver, from the console you can run this (obviously with your phone connected) and send the SMS.

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:CCXXXXXXXXXX --es sms_body "SMS BODY GOES HERE" --ez exit_on_sent true
adb shell input keyevent 22
adb shell input keyevent 66
```

You can save this in a script and then be called via PHP shell_exec () function through there and integrate everything you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Android SMS Server app](https://github.com/umer0586/AndroidSMSServer) to send SMS from android device using `http request`.

So in `PHP` you can use [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to send `http request` to [Android SMS Server app](https://github.com/umer0586/AndroidSMSServer) to send SMS.

```
<?php
    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.0.102:8081/sendSMS");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(
        array(

            'phone'  => "03476030148",
            'message' => "Your verification code is 1234"
            )
        ));

    //So that curl_exec returns the contents of the cURL; rather than echoing it
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

    //execute post
    $jsonResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $jsonResponse;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning: extreme elegance ahead.

If you want to be able to send SMS from PHP by using code as simple as:

```
mail('0981234567@catchall.domain.com', '', 'SMS Message here'); // PHP
```

then you can immediately go to: https://github.com/evorion/SMSGateway

It's just incredibly easy to use and even works when your phone is not online the whole time.

Comment: Search "SMS Gateway" on Google Play app store and there are several ready-to-use apps. Ones using Email as in this answer and ones using local server, custom http sources etc.